# Can the Bitcoin script make a Google search?

Tags: script

This very interesting [CCN Money article](http://finance.fortune.cnn.com/2014/01/21/bitcoin-platform/) states

> a script uses a data input such as a regular Google search to monitor
>   real-world events that would automatically trigger disbursements or
>   other actions

This part of the article suggests that the Bitcoin script could monitor external events, such as the result of a Google search, to trigger transfers. Can the Bitcoin script really do that?

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts#Example_4:_Using_external_state are helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin scripts are intentionally very limited, and can only access data inherent to the transaction (not even the blockchain it is in), in order to guarantee consistency (a script's validity cannot change over time).

However, there do exist ways to integrate external state into Bitcoin, through the use of oracles. See [this wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts#Example_4%3a_Using_external_state) for more information about those.